# truecrypt 7.1a requires Mac OS X 10.4 or later on Yosemite 10.10

Tags: macos, encryption, truecrypt

After reading articles about the state of Truecrypt in February 2015, I decided to download the last stable version of Truecrypt that allows full usage of Truecrypt: that is, version 7.1a

> 7.2 version that can only be used to view, but no longer to create new, TrueCrypt volumes.

see https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm

I then proceeded to install this on my Mac, running on Yosemite 10.10

But I got the error message "truecrypt 7.1a requires  Mac OS X 10.4 or later", see below.

[image: truecrypt 7.1a requires Mac OS X 10.4 or later on Yosemite 10.10]

I guess it's simply a schoolboy error from a developer of the Truecrypt team, as it considers 10.4 being above 10.10, or maybe it's rather Apple who messed up & should have consistantly used 2 digits after the dot (i.e. use 10.04 rather than 10.4).

In any case, I find myself unable to install Truecrypt. Anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

1. Copy the mpkg from inside the downloaded disk image onto your Desktop.
2. Right click the mpkg file and choose Show Package Contents, then open the Contents folder.
3. Open distribution.dist with a text editor.
4. Remove lines 13 to 18.

   [image]
5. Save the file and open the mpkg normally.

Comment: Found the exact same guidelines on https://lazymind.me/2014/10/install-truecrypt-on-mac-osx-yosemite-10-10/

Comment: Note that one has to move the mpkg off the mounted dmg otherwise file is read-only.

Comment: great answer! - what a sad bug though that the OS version is compared as string, so 10.10 < 10.4 :-(

Comment: Ugh, now in Catalina, looks it won't open at all because of the discontinued support for 32-bit applications.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Terminal and enter
  `sudo nano /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`
  and enter your admin password.
- Change the two strings "10.10" to "10.9". Leave the minor version number (e.g. 0, 1, 2...) like it is. Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write the file to disk.
- Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to quit nano
- Leave open the Terminal window.
- Install TrueCrypt 7.1a
- after the installation is finished change to Terminal and enter
  `sudo nano /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` again
- Change the two strings "10.9" back to "10.10". Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write the file to disk.
- Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to quit nano
- enter `cat /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` to recheck the correct system version (e.g. 10.10.2 or whatever it was).

Comment: Does the job I suppose. But I'd rather change the install script of truecrypt rather than touch the OS config files.

Comment: @AdrienBe That's true...probably it's a bit faster but more dangerous

Comment: Please do not offer solutions that tamper with system files and affect whole system rather than the application involved in the question.

Comment: @EugeneBujak Your point has merit, but please make it about what you are comfortable and not about telling someone what not to write here. I learn a lot from the answers (even unsafe ones or ones you shouldn't do without a backup net) that stray from what's trivially undoable.

Answer (score -1):

At step 4. why not simply correct the bug line 13 as :

```
    if(!(system.version.ProductVersion >= '10.04.0' )) {
```

etc.

Comment: Because this isn't any more ‘correct’, `'10.3' >= '10.04.0'` is true but that clearly shouldn't be. The logic condition needs to be more advanced to test the product version correctly.