# Mobile data not turning off for some apps iOS 8.4.1

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-data

I am unable to turn off mobile data for some apps.  Facebook, Cotap, Youtube and some others.  Yet some of the apps I can turn mobile data off for e.g App Store.

I recently upgraded to 8.4.1 on my iPhone 4s.

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

There's a bug which occurs sometimes where the CellularData.db is corrupted/malformed and iOS can't write the preferences to it.

You can fix this by deleting the file, located in `/var/wireless/Library/Databases/CellularUsage.db`.

Source: [Fix cellular data app preferences not being saved on iOS 7](https://georgegarside.com/blog/ios/cellular-data-app-preferences-not-saving-on-ios-7/)

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be jailbroken?

Comment: @Red Nothing wrong with answers that require a jailbreak, and theoretically that path should be writable.

Comment: Still, I don't think that everyone wants to jailbreak or use an iOS file manager.

Comment: @Red ["Your point has merit, but please make it about what you are comfortable and not about telling someone what not to write here. I learn a lot from the answers (even unsafe ones or ones you shouldn't do without a backup net) that stray from what's trivially undoable." — bmike](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173879/truecrypt-7-1a-requires-mac-os-x-10-4-or-later-on-yosemite-10-10/173880#comment214314_173881)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a bug in iOS to me. The best thing that you can do is wait until iOS 9 launches in a couple of weeks. iOS 9 should address many bugs and improve the performance of your iPhone, (even a 4S) so I highly recommend updating when iOS 9 gets a public release.